# Can all submodules of a given module be opened in a single statement in F#?

Tags: module, f#

I have something like this at some part in my app:

```
open ModuleX
open ModuleX.Submodule1
open ModuleX.Submodule2
open ModuleX.Submodule3
open ModuleX.Submodule4
open ModuleX.Submodule5
open ModuleX.Submodule6
```

Is there some way of simply doing:

```
open ModuleX
open ModuleX.*
```

The worst case in my app is a module that has 27 lines of module opening statements. I could break it into different files, but I would only be splitting the openings into different files, not really solving anything. Would you advice to "merge" submodules? Auto open wouldn't be okay for my case.

Or is it just something anyone doing F# has to deal with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to control this at the point of opening, but you can make these modules "automatically openable" at their declaration point. To do this, decorate them with `[<AutoOpen>]`:

```
module A =

  [<AutoOpen>]
  module B =
    let x = 5

  module C =
    let y = 6

open A

let z = x   // x is now available
let u = C.y // y still requires qualified access
```

People who bought `[<AutoOpen>]` also liked `[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]` :-)

```
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module C =
  let y = 6

open C // Compiler error
```

Comment: Well, I guess I will have to give a try to AutoOpen... maybe I like it.

Comment: When there's a line starting "people who bought...", how can you not upvote?!? :)